# Symfony Ajax, Transmit Data Array to controller

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, symfony

I'm trying to transmit an array from my twig file to another controller using Ajax.

My Ajax Code:

```
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()>= $(document).height()){
            getmoredata();
        }

    })

    var page = 1;

    function getmoredata(array_data_file) {
        var array_data_file = { {{ announces }} } ;
        var theurl = '{{ path('announce_page', {'id': "id", 'game': game}) }}'; 
        theurl = theurl.replace("id", page);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: {data_array:array_data_file},
            url: theurl,
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                    $("#content").append(response.classifiedList);
                    page = page + 1;
                    $('#spinner').hide();
                    console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Controller code:

```
    public function pageAction(Request $request, $id, $game)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    //$announces = $em->getRepository('PlatformBundle:Announce')->byGame($game);
    $announces = $request->request->get('data_array');
    $list = $this->renderView('announce/result.html.twig', array(
        'announces' => $announces,
        'game' => $game
    ));

    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $response->setData(array('classifiedList' => $list));
    return $response;

}
```

Two problem about my code:

First is about getting a javascript variable with my entity announce who contains a lot of thing.

```
var array_data_file = { {{ announces }} } ;
```

This don't work so i try something like that

```
var array_data_file ={{ announces|json_encode() }};
```

But when i make an alert(array_data_file);
I got something like that:

> object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Second thing, i got always a variable NULL from my controller

```
$announces = $request->request->get('data_array');
```

This code is for infinite scrolling system for posting infinite announce in my page. I would like to transmit my announce from my index page for not making a new research in the database like this:

```
$announces = $em->getRepository('PlatformBundle:Announce')->byUser($user);
```

Any solution for this?

Thanks everybody

EDIT:

I almost finish to solved my problem.

I have install
and now i can use this command to have a variable format with json.

```
var contactsArray = "{{ announces|serialize('json') }}";
```

Now my variable contains a very long string string.

I have change the type"GET" to "POST" because my url was too long.

Now back to my controller, i take from POST my variable

```
$data = $request->request->get('data_array');
```

But it's still a very long string and i try to back to my entity with this:

```
$serializer = $this->container->get('jms_serializer');
$announces = $serializer->deserialize($data, 'Wolk\PlatformBundle\Entity\Announce', 'json');
```

but i have an error like that

```
"Could not decode JSON, syntax error - malformed JSON."
```

The thing is, i read some post and they said to insert in each variable of my entities

> - @JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Type("string")

But it's too long, i have a lot of variable and entity from my announce x/

Here i am

Comment: do you have an error ? what is the problem ?

Comment: I give more detail in my post

Comment: im not sure but for the 1 problem you have to loop throw your $announces to create the array_data_file . and for the seconde you send the data as GET so in your controller  Action change $request->request->get('data_array'); by $request->query->get('data_array');

Comment: $announces = $request->query->get('data_array'); is working but i didn't understand about the first problem. How to make a loop for creating an array?

Comment: For sending ajax to a controller in symfony I believe the best way is to use routes. This question has a fairly comprehensive answer, basically install FOSJsRouting bundle and expose the route in routing.yml and then call the controller action needed via the route. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27089855/symfony-routing-ajax-get-method

Comment: {{ announces|json_encode() }} should work. Your alert is printing it because alert can't make a tostring on array/object. Try console.log or your browser debugger

Comment: I update my post, you can see, where i am

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteMace it's just an idea, but, why are you trying to pass all your entities to your controller to get the next X entities ? Maybe the last index you got should be enough no ?